# What does a private constructor do?

Tags: java, integer

I am looking at an `IntegerCache` class, but it has a usage I can't understand. There is a `private` constructor on the last line, but I don't understand the purpose. What does it do?

```
private static class IntegerCache {
    static final int low = -128;
    static final int high;
    static final Integer cache[];

    static {
        // high value may be configured by property
        int h = 127;
        String integerCacheHighPropValue =
        sun.misc.VM.getSavedProperty("java.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high");
        if (integerCacheHighPropValue != null) {
            try {
                int i = parseInt(integerCacheHighPropValue);
                i = Math.max(i, 127);
                // Maximum array size is Integer.MAX_VALUE
                h = Math.min(i, Integer.MAX_VALUE - (-low) -1);
            } catch( NumberFormatException nfe) {
                // If the property cannot be parsed into an int, ignore it.
            }
        }
        high = h;

        cache = new Integer[(high - low) + 1];
        int j = low;
        for(int k = 0; k < cache.length; k++)
            cache[k] = new Integer(j++);

        // range [-128, 127] must be interned (JLS7 5.1.7)
        assert IntegerCache.high >= 127;
    }

    private IntegerCache() {}
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

That is an empty constructor that is also `private`, preventing instantiation of the the class. The class is intended to be used only for its static properties and no instance of the class can be created.

Comment: I get it , thanks~

Answer (score 3):

By default, the Java compiler will *insert* an empty `public` constructor if no constructor is provided. By explicitly adding an empty `private` constructor

```
private IntegerCache() {}
```

the compiler will not add a default constructor. See also [JLS-8.8.9. Default Constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9) **and** [JLS-8.8.10. Preventing Instantiation of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.10) which says (in part)

> A class can be designed to prevent code outside the class declaration from creating instances of the class by declaring at least one constructor, to prevent the creation of a default constructor, and by declaring all constructors to be `private`.
>
> A `public` class can likewise prevent the creation of instances outside its package by declaring at least one constructor, to prevent creation of a default constructor with `public` access, and by declaring no constructor that is public.

Comment: I get it , thanks~